# CImageList exception in MFC programming VS-2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm following example 8a of a MFC book entitled (Programming with Microsoft Visual C++ .NET, Sixth Edition).

However when I tried to compile it I faced with the following exceptions:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x78a782ac (mfc90ud.dll) in Ex08a.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.
```

which points to

```
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));
    return CImageList::FromHandle((HIMAGELIST)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, LVM_SETIMAGELIST,
       nImageList, (LPARAM)pImageList->GetSafeHandle()));
}
```

in `afxcmn.inl`

Since I'm using visual studio 2008, there are differences between my code and Book's code.

The following lines are some of those discrepancies:

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST1, &CEx08aDialog::OnLvnItemChangedListview1)
ON_NOTIFY(TVN_SELCHANGED, IDC_TREEVIEW1, &CEx08aDialog::OnTvnSelchangedTreeview1)

static char* color[]={"white","black","red","blue","yellow","cyan","purple","green"};
pList->InsertItem(n,(LPCTSTR)color[n],n);
```

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: "location 0x00000020" implies an attempt to access a member variable via a pointer that is set to NULL (member offset within the class is 32 bytes). Take a look around when you get the exception and look for that NULL object (probably that very CListCtrl you've called, but I can't say for sure).

Comment: @eran: your comment should be an answer IMHO

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator, I didn't make it an answer because it's incomplete. Given the limited amount of information on the question, I can't say which pointer is set to NULL, and I obviously can't say why. If I get some feedback from the OP, I might turn it into an answer.